# Цикл с двумя DataGridView

Tags: c#, циклы, datagridview

На форме имеются два *dataGridView* 7 и 8.

В 7 загружаются данные из *excel* в виде таблицы, в 8 загружается база с сервера, и необходимо пройти циклом по поиску и нахождению фамилий из dgv7 по dgv8. Если находит, то окрашивает в dgv7 зеленым цветом саму ячейку с совпадением. получилось сделать только один цикл, который будет пробегать и искать по жесткой привязке к слову. Пробовал вот так, не получилось. Как я понимаю нужно два цикла, но как их сделать?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView7.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView7.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == dataGridView8.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
    {
        dataGridView7.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) Зачем `Convert.ToBoolean`? У вас сравнение возвращает что-то другое? (2) Почему `ToString` перед сравнением? Это ж не PHP. (3) Почему сравнение на уровне UI-кода? Вы должны работать не с строками, а с осмысленными типизированными сущностями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно последовательный поиск по двум гридам делается так

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount-1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.RowCount-1; j++)
          {
          }
}
```